# Executing Multiple or Three Queries at Once

Tags: php, multi-query

I'm currently creating an online reservation system.

How can I execute multiple queries at once?

I'm already using mysqli_muti_query. I have three queries to execute.

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO db (name,picuploc,lname,pnumber,age,email,address,city,zipcode,ticketid,pickuptime,dropofftime,dropoffloc,vehicle,plateno,totalprice,date_registered) VALUES ('$first','$pickuploc','$lname','$pnumber','$age','$email','$address','$city','$zip','$ticket','$pickup','$dropoff','$dropoffloc','$car','$plate','$all', NOW());";

$sql .= "UPDATE vehicles set quantity = quantity - $age WHERE vehicle = '$car' AND parent = '$ye' ";

$sql .= "UPDATE vehicles set status = '$un'  WHERE plateno = '$plate' "; ?>
```

Comment: Your 2nd query does not have an ending semi colon - `;` -> `... AND parent = '$ye'; ";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add  semicolon after each statement:

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO db (name,picuploc,lname,pnumber,age,email,address,city,zipcode,ticketid,pickuptime,dropofftime,dropoffloc,vehicle,plateno,totalprice,date_registered) VALUES ('$first','$pickuploc','$lname','$pnumber','$age','$email','$address','$city','$zip','$ticket','$pickup','$dropoff','$dropoffloc','$car','$plate','$all', NOW());";

$sql .= "UPDATE vehicles set quantity = quantity - $age WHERE vehicle = '$car' AND parent = '$ye' ;";

$sql .= "UPDATE vehicles set status = '$un'  WHERE plateno = '$plate' ;";
```

Comment: the semicolon at the end of the last query is not needed, and may actually cause the query to fail - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#115325

Comment: @Sean last semicolon not effect any cause http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#113840

Answer (score 0):

If supported by your database, I'd suggest that you run your queries separately and wrap them into a single transaction.

```
$conn->begin_transaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO db (name,picuploc,lname,pnumber,age,email,address,city,zipcode,ticketid,pickuptime,dropofftime,dropoffloc,vehicle,plateno,totalprice,date_registered) VALUES ('$first','$pickuploc','$lname','$pnumber','$age','$email','$address','$city','$zip','$ticket','$pickup','$dropoff','$dropoffloc','$car','$plate','$all', NOW());";
$conn->query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE vehicles set quantity = quantity - $age WHERE vehicle = '$car' AND parent = '$ye';";
$conn->query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE vehicles set status = '$un'  WHERE plateno = '$plate';";
$conn->query($sql);

$conn->commit();
```

I'd also suggest that you use prepared statements with parameters rather than including values directly into your query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP `mysqli_multi_query-`function.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO db (name,picuploc,lname,pnumber,age,email,address,city,zipcode,ticketid,pickuptime,dropofftime,dropoffloc,vehicle,plateno,totalprice,date_registered) VALUES ('$first','$pickuploc','$lname','$pnumber','$age','$email','$address','$city','$zip','$ticket','$pickup','$dropoff','$dropoffloc','$car','$plate','$all', NOW());";

$sql .= "UPDATE vehicles set quantity = quantity - $age WHERE vehicle = '$car' AND parent = '$ye' ;";

$sql .= "UPDATE vehicles set status = '$un'  WHERE plateno = '$plate' ;"; 

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {

}
```